# python how to overcome global interpretor lock

Tags: python

I have implemented tool to extract the data from clear quest server using python. I need to do lot of searches in clearquest so I have implemented it using threading.
To do that i try to open individual clearquest session for each thread. When I try to run this I am getting Run Time error and none of the clearquest session opened correctly.

I did bit of research on internet and found that it's because of Global Interpretor Lock in python. I would like to know how to overcome this GIL...Any idea would be much appreciated

Comment: What's the actual error message? In general, the GIL will just prevent you from getting good performance by making a CPU-bound program threaded, not give errors.

Comment: clearquest server is throwing exception and not allowing to open the session when threaded..however, the same code works when I try to open the session normally with out thread

Comment: If clearquest doesn't allow concurrent connections, then you'll have the same problem regardless of whether you use threads or processes.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using threads, use different processes and use some sort of IPC to communicate between each process.

Comment: The ``multiprocessing`` package from Python 2.6+ would be a good candidate: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you'll have RuntimeErrors because of the GIL. Can you paste the traceback? If you have some critical parts of the code that are not re entrant, you'll have to isolate them using some concurrency primitives.

The main issue with the GIL is that it will forcibly serialise computation. The result is reduced throughput and scaling.